# journalctl - stop following without exiting pager

Tags: systemd, journald, less

If I do:

```
journalctl -u my-service
```

then a `Shift-F` to follow while paging, how do I `(interrupt to abort)` without exiting the pager?

With `less`, I typically just `^C`, but if I do that in journalctl, it exits the entire pager.

Answer (score 7):

You *are* using `less` at that point, but ^C is behaving differently due to how it was invoked by `journalctl`. The flags that journalctl passes to `less` include the following defaults:

```
 FRSXMK
```

Of these, I think the "K" option applies here:

> **-K or --quit-on-intr**
>                 Causes less to exit immediately (with status 2) when an interrupt character (usually ^C) is typed.  Normally, an interrupt 
>   character  causes  less  to
>                 stop  whatever it is doing and return to its command prompt.  Note that use of this option makes it impossible to return to
>   the command prompt from the
>                 "F" command.

So, setting $SYSTEMD_LESS in your environment and omitting the "K" option *should* resolve the issue, it didn't work on my test on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
 SYSTEMD_LESS="FRSXM"journalctl -u nginx
```

However, you can get the behavior you want confirm that the K flag is related by comparing the behavior of the following variations:

```
# ^C after Shift-F does not completely quit
journalctl -u nginx | less -FRSXM

# ^C after Shift-F completely quits
journalctl -u nginx | less -FRSXMK
```

Comment: I have the same problem setting `SYSTEMD_LESS`, but I confirmed this *does* change the flags sent to `less`. You can check by finding the PID of `less` and doing `hd /proc/<pid>/environ`. Look for the environment variable `LESS`. It will be there but empty (normally it's `FRSXMK`). You can also type `_K` in less itself to see whether that flag is set. Normally it is. If you pass `SYSTEMD_LESS=` it isn't. I think the journalctl process is signaling the pager when it gets `SIGINT`, which is why `less` dies regardless of that setting.

Comment: Here's a hacky proof-of-concept that shows how you can get around this: https://gist.github.com/chriskuehl/9ab4c74c19f2f4cb883744171335ac44

Answer (score 0):

I also just experienced this annoying quirk.
Setting `SYSTEMD_LESS` indeed does not work because journalctl will send a `SIGTERM` to the pager when it receives a ^C.

My "solution" was to use a bash alias like this:

```
alias log='SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 journalctl | less -FRSXM'
```

This overrides the default pager and does not exit when you interrupt follow.
The environment variable `SYSTEMD_COLORS` seems to be the only way to have colors and keep less running after a `SIGINT`.

This works on my Debian 9 installation.

Comment: Hmm, this stopped following. But so did `journalctl | less`, might be a bug.